# Does [C++11: 12.8/7] make sense?

Tags: c++, c++11

> `[C++11: 12.8/7]:` If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy constructor, one is declared implicitly. **If the class definition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the implicitly declared copy constructor is defined as deleted; *otherwise, it is defined as defaulted (8.4)***. The latter case is deprecated if the class has a user-declared copy assignment operator or a user-declared destructor. Thus, for the class definition
>
> ```
> struct X {
>    X(const X&, int);
> };
> ```
>
> a copy constructor is implicitly-declared. If the user-declared constructor is later defined as
>
> ```
> X::X(const X& x, int i =0) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> then any use of `X`’s copy constructor is ill-formed because of the **ambiguity**; no diagnostic is required.

This doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

How does the code sample introduced by "thus" have anything to do with the "latter" case that I highlighted in italics?

My understanding so far is that:

- If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy constructor, and
- the class definition does not declare a move constructor or move assignment operator, and
- the class has a use-declared copy assignment operator or a user-declared destructor, then
- *the implicitly-defined copy constructor is defined as `default`ed, and this is deprecated*.

This seems odd in itself, that a standard-mandated behaviour is — in the same breath — deprecated. Does this mean that having a class that satisfies those three conditions is deprecated?

And what does the code sample have to do with it? That constructor is not a copy constructor, move constructor, move assignment operator, copy assignment operator or a user-declared destructor; it's just a user-declared constructor, no? Where's this "ambiguity"?

Could someone decode this passage for me?

Comment: I'm more confused by a default parameter in a function definition.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like an odd example in an already oddly-arranged paragraph.

Comment: @SimonRichter you can put them in either the declaration or the definition, but not both, obviously. Myself, I've never put it in the definition...

Comment: @LiamM: Presumably there's a requirement a compile-time about the default parameter being visible to the calling scope. _[edit: 8.3.6 doesn't appear to say so, but (at least for member functions, the only example given of default arguments in **defining** declarations being valid, though this is not explicitly prohibited elsewhere) I can't see how else it would work.]_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does this mean that having a class that satisfies those three conditions is deprecated?

Yes; if you have a use-declared copy-assignment operator or destructor, you should also declare a copy constructor. It's basically just saying that your class should follow the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) (or Five, or whatever it's called in C++11).

> This seems odd in itself, that a standard-mandated behaviour is — in the same breath — deprecated.

The behaviour is mandated by the standard because that was the behaviour in C++03 - changing it would break legacy code. Just as the standard defines the behaviour of (for example) dynamic exception specifications, and also deprecates them.

> How does the code sample introduced by "thus" have anything to do with the "latter" case that I highlighted in italics?

It doesn't have anything to do with the "latter" case.

It is an illustration of a potential problem caused by the normal behaviour defined by the clause: there will be a conflict between an implicitly-declared copy constructor, and a user-declared constructor with default arguments such that it can be called like a copy constructor.

> Where's this "ambiguity"?

Consider the code:

```
X x1;  // assume there's also a default constructor
X x2(x);
```

Should `x2` be initialised with the user-declared constructor (with the second argument taking its default value), or the implicitly-declared copy constructor? Both are an equally good match for the usage. That is the ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks; good breakdown. :) There should be a few more line breaks in the standard paragraph, methinks.

Answer (score 3):

Just to answer the 2nd part. The ambiguity is due to the default parameter `int i = 0`, which allows that constructor to be called with only the first argument `const X& x`, which allows it to be used as a copy constructor as well because it is compatible with the signature `X(const X& x)` (§12.8/2 for the exact text). This conflicts with the implicit copy constructor, thus the ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be clarifying the role of the move constructor and how it affects the copy constructor. It's saying that if you declare a move constructor or a move assignment operator, then there will be no implicit copy constructor. If you've defined your own copy constructor or copy assignment operator, you can disregard the  bit you've placed in **bold** text.

I think the point of the example was to show that for the class:

```
struct X {
   X(const X&, int);
};
```

A copy constructor is implicitly defined, because there is no user defined copy constructor. However if you provide a default value for the second int argument (as they've done), then a call to:

```
X newX(oldX);
```

Could be a call to the user defined constructor or the copy constructor: This is the ambiguity they speak of.

Comment: Oh, because of the default argument. Duh to me.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oh well, at least that was something simple.

Comment: "the user defined constructor or the copy constructor" <- is ambiguous. Both are copy constructors.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb But only one is defined by the user, and I refer to the copy constructor as that which is implicitly defined in the paragraph above that.